# print an array as stack

Tags: ruby, arrays, stack

I am trying to split a sentence by space, store it into any array and then print it as a stack(backward).

This is my attempt:

```
sentence =  "The quick fox "    
stack = sentence.split
print stack.pop until stack.empty? # => fox quick The
```

This looks a bit weird to me, I am not sure if you guys could recommend me a better solution? Thanks.

Comment: Can you say why you must treat it as a stack?  Eric Walker's answer is idiomatic Ruby, clear and concise.

Comment: Agreed, the better solution is to not erroneously treat an array as a stack.

Comment: Is this a homework problem, where you have to work with a stack?

Comment: +1 @EricWalker, that was going to be my question. I think it is, and that it's a poor question and a poor exercise.

Comment: @theTinMan: there should be an SE site for homework problems. :)  I hate to discourage young students by downvoting their questions.

Comment: This is not a homework! I have already post my code and just want to see a better one.

Comment: Better code and treating the array as a stack are contradictory in this case.

Comment: You are right, I have just come from a java background, I googled and find out that in ruby we can demonstrate a stack using an array, thats why I have just asked this.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
"The quick fox ".split.reverse.join(" ")
```

Comment: tnx, looks nice; but I want to use array as stack.

Comment: "I want to use array as stack". While it's always possible to use an array as a stack, there are times it makes sense, and other times it makes none. This is the later of the two because it takes a lot more work to treat it as a stack when all you want to do is reverse a list.

Answer (score 1):

To add a space after each word:

```
sentence =  "The quick fox "
stack = sentence.split
until stack.empty?
  print stack.pop
  print ' ' unless stack.empty?
end
# => fox quick the
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I want the array to be printed backward.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "The quick fox "
stack = s.split
until stack.empty? do stack.shift end
```

`shift`, instead of `pop` is what you are looking for.

Additional wisdom: just like `pop` has a corresponding `push`, `shift` has a corresponding `unshift`.

Answer (score 0):

```
stack = "The quick fox ".split
stack.size.times{ puts stack.pop }
```

But I prefer OP's `pop until empty?` syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
print *"The quick fox ".strip.split.reverse.map{|w| " #{w}"}
```

But your requirement of having a stack and printing them separated by a space is contradictory. When you have a list, the Ruby's standard way of output (beside inspect) is to output each item on a different line like this:

```
puts "The quick fox ".strip.split.reverse
```